# mac vscode bash: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name

Tags: bash, macos, visual-studio-code, shopt

Running vscode on Mac. I updated the Mac bash version and, as you can see the built-in vscode terminal shows the same version of bash as that of the Mac terminal. When I source my .bash_profile, I get the `invalid shell option name` error in the vscode terminal. What is causing this?

FWIW - the Terminal > Integrated > Shell: Osx is set to `bin/bash`, if that is not obvious. And, my SHELL variable is the same.

[image]

Comment: `bash --version` tells you what version you'd start if you ran the command `bash`, not what version of bash you're running *now*.

Comment: Run `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` instead.

Comment: To be clear, `globstar` was added in bash 4.0, and MacOS `/bin/bash` is 3.2. Thus, the issue is *clearly* that you're running the Apple-provided instance of bash from `/bin`, not the newer one that's added to the PATH in your dotfiles after the older version is already started.

Comment: (BTW, it's pertinent/important to describe *how* you installed a newer bash; it's configured a bit differently based on whether you use Nixpkgs, or MacPorts, or HomeBrew, or built your own by hand; btw, of those options, the list is in my suggested order of preference).

Comment: changing the version in vscode preferences to point to /usr/local/bin/bash rather than /bin/bash did the trick. i did understand, btw, all about globstar being a 4.x thing, thus the reason i upgraded bash in the first place - likely via homebrew. I did that months ago.

Comment: In PhpStorm (or any other of the JetBrains IDEs) you have to change the "Shell Path" under Tools-->Terminal from `/bin/bash` to `/usr/local/bin/bash` or whatever the path to the new version of bash is.